# Customizing Ribbon Control in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ribbon

I have a custom document library and i want to disable the download as a copy option available in the ribbon control. Please note this disabling should be applicable only to this particular document library and it should not be reflected in other document libraries.

[image]

Scripting and changing the default behaviour in master page happens to affect all document libraries so is there any other options available?

Thanks!

Comment: We injected a script that will disable the entire ribbon control. This script will run only if the document library content type matches the predefined type. This is a temporary relief, but the main objective is to disable the particular download button alone...Please suggest any alternatives